# Unable to handle click event on button-ified checkbox in Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, checkbox

Bootstrap 4 can present checkboxes and their labels to look like buttons. The doc for that can be found here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

In the case where checkboxes and labels are presented as such (and not as buttons), handling click events on the input element is easy enough. But once the required CSS classes and attributes are added to present these as buttons, handling the same events is not as trivial. Some code would be in order here:

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox
  </label>
</div>

// The JS
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  alert('Click!');
});
```

Here's a not-so-working working example: http://codepen.io/jfvaren/pen/QdwmpV

The intention here is to display a "Click!" alert once the "Checkbox" is clicked. If the "data-toggle" attribute is removed, it works fine (with the exception that the checkbox is still visible). It seems like Bootstrap simply ditches all jQuery-registered event listeners on the checkbox element, which is kind of rude. I know I can listen for click events on the label element instead, but that is not desired for the case I'm working on.

Any idea how I could get around this and still have an out-of-the-box Bootstrap markup?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn  btn-primary">
      <div class ="col-xs-1 extra">
      <input  type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"/> 
        </div>

           <label >
           Checkbox 1
          </label>

      </div>
   </div>
```

Notice the **extra** class. Looks like bootstrap shrinked the checkbox container so I wrapped it into another div with the class **extra** so I can easily edit the size of checkbox because It's harder to edit checkbox properties on css. Now you just have to set the height of **extra** to some value and change the jquery selector to **".extra"**.

---

Also there is no need for the label to wrap the checkbox. I think it is a better idea to use divs to wrap content and set css properties and use labels just for text. That is what I did.

Comment: I would like to stick to vanilla Bootstrap 4 markup as much as possible. If I have to change the markup a whole lot, the Bootstrap ROI diminishes. And like I mentioned in the question, I could just place my event listener on the label element. My question was thus more JS related than markup related. I've updated the question to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: I see now. Looks like bootstrap uses preventDefault() on checkboxes and radio buttons for that case (data-toggle button) to avoid double clicks. I guess the only way is to remove that from the js file,